# how to solve Object reference not set to an instance of an object in Power BI and the source file is an Excel Macro file

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I had created a Power BI file and had shared it with my team via Sharepoint as well as via mails. But whenever they try to open the file, they are getting the error as "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".
The source file is an Excel Macro file.
I had tried downloading the .pbix file myself, but it isn't giving me any error, I am not able to identify any root cause.
Please guide me on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" is not for anything specific. Issues can be related to different problematic area. You can try this below to search your luck-

1. Download the latest version of Power BI desktop
2. Try to match the version (32/64 bit) between your OS and Power BI desktop software
3. reconnect the data source and then check everything works for you or not after publishing the report